# How to renumber remaining table rows after .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

The Javascript increments each visible number in these dynamically generated rows of a static table.

The jQuery dutifully hides each row when clicked, but, of course, the numbers don't change. How can I use jQuery to re-number the rows when the visitor is done removing the unwanted lines? I want the user to click 'renumber' to renumber the remaining rows correctly. What I have didn't work :-)

Help is deeply appreciated.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var keepTrack = 1;      
 </script>
 <table>
 <tr><td colspan="2" id="renumber">renumber</td></tr>

 <tr id="sWH1">
 <td>
 <script>
 document.write(keepTrack);keepTrack++;
 </script></td>
 <td>someWordsHere</td></tr>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#sWH1").click(function() {
$("#sWH1").hide(100);}); 
 });</script>


 <tr id="sWH2">
 <td>
 <script>
 document.write(keepTrack);keepTrack++;
 </script></td>
 <td>someWordsHere</td></tr>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#sWH2").click(function() {
 $("#sWH2").hide(100);}); 
  });</script>


 <tr id="sWH3">
 <td>
 <script>
 document.write(keepTrack);keepTrack++;
 </script></td>
 <td>someWordsHere</td></tr>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#sWH3").click(function() {
 $("#sWH3").hide(100);}); 
  });</script>

 </table>

 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#renumber").click(function() {
 'magically renumber the remaining table rows'
 });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The straightforward answer**

To renumber the rows you can use the `each()` method that allows you to iterate over a set of elements (the rows in this case) and provides an `i` enumerator parameter.

A general example:

```
$(some-tr-selector).each(function(i) {
    $(this).children(some-td-selector).text(i+1);
});
```

Now to do this, you'll need to define better selectors. The problem with your current code is that your selectors are too specific. This prevents you from creating general event handlers, instead of creating a click handler for each row.

**How to improve your code**

Consider setting a class for the relevant numbered rows. This will allow you to create a single click handler for all rows and make the relevant rows much easier to select when renumbering.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2" id="renumber">renumber</td></tr>
    <tr class="numbered_row">
        <td class="row_number"></td>
        <td>someWordsHere</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="numbered_row">
        <td class="row_number"></td>
        <td>someWordsHere</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="numbered_row">
        <td class="row_number"></td>
        <td>someWordsHere</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Number all rows onload
    $('table tr.numbered_row').each(function(i) {
        $(this).children('.row_number').text(i+1);
    });

     // Row click handler
    $('table tr.numbered_row').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide(100);
    });

     // Renumber click handler
    $('#renumber').on('click', function() {
        $('table tr.numbered_row:visible').each(function(i) { // Iterate over all _visible_ rows
            $(this).children('.row_number').text(i+1);
        });
    });
});
```

Note how by adding two classes `numbered_row` and `row_number` we are able to do everything efficiently in one block of code: initial numbering of the rows, a single click handler to hide them and the renumbering action.

**An even more general approach**

If you wanted, you could make this even more general and efficient, by chaining the `each()` and `on()` methods as well as handling the renumbering within the `on()` each time a row is hidden.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Number all rows onload
    $('table tr.numbered_row').each(function(i) {
        $(this).children('.row_number').text(i+1);
     // Row click handler
    }).on('click', function() {
         // Hide current row
        $(this).hide(100);
         // Renumber visible rows
        $('table tr.numbered_row:visible').each(function(i) { // Iterate over all _visible_ rows
            $(this).children('.row_number').text(i+1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay Boaz, I have it fully deployed and it is just really smooth. Efficiently written, and a real time saver. Just wanted to take a last pass to really say thank you.

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER Just for reference, updated the answer with the an even more generalized approach for this case.

Comment: Thanks Boaz, but I ain't touchin' it. I woiks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

http://jsbin.com/ufahac/1/edit

This is your code with few changes: the table has an id=myTable
and ***'magically renumber the remaining table rows'*** has been replaced with

```
$('#myTable tr[id]:visible').each(function(i){
   $(this).find('td:first').text(i+1);
})
```

Comment: This is interesting too. I'll keep this one around for reference, but honestly, I'm so happy with what Boaz provided, I just moving to the next problem. Thanks leoinfo!